# Android get request/attribute from servlet

Tags: android, servlets, attributes

I got existing servlet, and i am using android to connect with it. I was wondering does android able to get the request information from the servlet after it called ? Is that any others method to do so if it cannot be retrieve, like creating the new servlet(this is my least choice). The result i get back from the servlet is the **listing-details.jsp** information.

The request I want to get is this, the information of **trans** list

```
request.setAttribute("transactions",trans);
```

The servlet

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String sort;
    String propertyID= request.getParameter("pid");
    Property result = PropertyManager.getInstance().searchPropertyByID(propertyID);
    sort = request.getParameter("transort");
    String role = "";
    List<Transaction> trans = TransactionManager.getInstance().searchTransactionByName(result.getProperty_district(),result.getProperty_name(),sort);

    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
    .getRequestDispatcher("listing-details.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("property", result);
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("property");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("property",result);
    request.setAttribute("transactions",trans);
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

Here is my Android activity and the URL

```
URL : http://xxxx/ListingDetailServlet

 private class GetListingDetail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        //Log.i(TAG, "BEfore input stream ");
        try {
            InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                output.append(s);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    public InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside inputstream ");
        InputStream stream = null;
        urlString = urlString + "?pid=pid624";//&transort=";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        try {

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream(); 
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
        Log.i(TAG, output);
    }
```